# Traverse digits in strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, traversal

I'm trying to consider a function that takes in a flat array of string decimal integers that represent nodes in a tree, each period connotes hierarchy in that tree. I'm trying to create `prevNode` and `nextNode` functions. that take three parameters `ids, id, planeLock`. If a node has no `prev` or `next` `id` then `false` is returned. If `planeLock` is `true` then instead of going to the next node in the tree (e.g. from `1` to `0.1`) it will go to the next node in that plane (eg. from `1` to `0`) otherwise know as it's sibling, and not it's siblings deepest child.

```
var ids = [
  '0',
  '0.1',
  '1',
  '2',
  '2.0',
  '2.1',
]
```

- `prevNode(ids, '0')` -> `false` // no prev node
- `prevNode(ids, '1', true)` -> `0` // pass true stays on same plane
- `prevNode(ids, '1')` -> `0.1` // prev node in tree
- `prevNode(ids, '2.0', true)` -> `false`
- `prevNode(ids, '2.0')` -> `2` // goes up one node

How can I parse these strings to get the desired results?

Comment: Are `ids` always in ascending order? If so, it's possible to implement, but each call `prevNode` will be essentially O(n).

Comment: Is the depth of the hierarchy always 2, or do you need a solution for arbitrary depth?

Comment: @raina77ow a `.sort() ` is necessary to confirm it's in descending order. The hierarchy is arbitrary depth and not limited to 2.

Comment: Do the nodes need to look for sequential integers, or just the next in order? For example, if you have `['0.1', '0.5']`, is that valid input, and should `nextNode(ids, '0.1', true)` return `'0.5'` or `false`?

Comment: Are `next` and `prev` based on their positions in the array, or by the numeric values in the node?

Comment: When `planeLock = true`, count the number of levels in the node with `ids.split(".").length`. Then loop until you get to the next or previous node with the same number of levels.

Comment: @nrabinowitz the way that array is generated will always have numerically sequential nodes, regardless your example should return `'0.5'`.

Comment: Checkout my incomplete answer below, the sibling properties (`planeLock`) is tripping me up. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var _ = require('lodash')

function compare (n1, n2) {
  var path1 = n1.split('.')
  var path2 = n2.split('.')
  var maxLen = Math.max(path1.length, path2.length)
  var i = 0
  while (i < maxLen) {
    if (!path1[i] || +path1[i] < +path2[i]) {
      return -1
    }
    if (!path2[i] || +path1[i] > +path2[i]) {
      return 1
    }
    i++
  }
  return 0
}

function subset (ids, id) {
  return _.filter(ids, function (_id) {
    var _idArr = _id.split('.')
    var idArr = id.split('.')
    var _idChop = _.take(_idArr, _idArr.length - 1).join('.')
    var idChop = _.take(idArr, idArr.length - 1).join('.')
    if (_idChop === idChop) return true
    return false
  })
}

function metaInfo (ids, id) {
  ids = ids.sort(compare)
  var idIndex = ids.indexOf(id)
  var meta = {}
  meta.prev = (ids[idIndex - 1]) ? ids[idIndex - 1] : false
  meta.next = (ids[idIndex + 1]) ? ids[idIndex + 1] : false
  var idsSubset = subset(ids, id)
  var idSubsetIndex = idsSubset.indexOf(id)
  meta.prevSibling = (idsSubset[idSubsetIndex - 1]) ? idsSubset[idSubsetIndex - 1] : false
  meta.nextSibling = (idsSubset[idSubsetIndex + 1]) ? idsSubset[idSubsetIndex + 1] : false
  return meta
}

var ids = [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '0.0.0', '0.0.1', '0.0', '1.0' ]

var val = metaInfo(ids, '1')
console.log(val)
```

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting `_.keys(ids).sort()` to do - that will take the indexes of the array (already sorted) and give you an array like `['0', '1', '2', ....]`

Comment: Hey sorry that was a remnant from something else. I was passing an object. Fixed!

Comment: That won't work either, unfortunately. You're dealing with strings, so you'll do a lexical sort - `"2.12" < "2.5"`

Comment: Updated, Thoughts on this? @nrabinowitz

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
function getLevel(id) {
  return id.split('.').length;
}

function siblingNode(ids, id, planeLock, goesBack) {
  var index = ids.indexOf(id);
  var level = getLevel(id);

  while (goesBack ? --index >= 0 : ++index < ids.length) {
    var currEl = ids[index];
    var currLevel = getLevel(currEl);
    if (!planeLock || currLevel === level) {
      return currEl;
    }
    if (currLevel < level) {
       break;
    }
  }
  return false; 
}

function prevNode(ids, id, planeLock) {
  return siblingNode(ids, id, planeLock, true);
}

function nextNode(ids, id, planeLock) {
  return siblingNode(ids, id, planeLock, false);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2z2kkcp5/). Apparently, there's a tradeoff between memoizing all the levels (speedy but costs memory) and not (vice versa). If the source array is dynamic, and you'll have to look for a place when inserting new items, I'd strongly recommend memoizing approach (as you'll have to check `level` at each insertion).

Answer (score 1):

Sorting the whole thing is a good approach. But if you want to extend this with additional functionality it may be better to convert your id list into a tree.

```
function createSortedTree(ids) {
  var tree = {name: "", id: "root", children: {}};
  function insert(tree, elem) {
    if(!tree.children[elem[0]]) {
      tree.children[elem[0]] = {
        id: elem[0],
        children: {},
        parent: tree,
        name: tree.id === "root" ? "" + elem[0] : tree.name + "." + elem[0]
      };
    }
    if(elem.length > 1) insert(tree.children[elem[0]], elem.slice(1));
  }
  for(i in ids) insert(tree, ids[i].split("."));

  function traverse(tree) {
    if(current) {
      current.next = tree;
      tree.prev = current;
    }
    current = tree;

    var children = Object.keys(tree.children)
                         .sort(function(a, b) {if(a < b) return -1; else if(a > b) return 1; else return 0;})
                         .map(function(key) {return tree.children[key]});
    for(i in children) {
      if(i > 0) children[i].prevPlane = children[i-1];
      if(i < children.length - 1) children[i].nextPlane = children[i+1];
      traverse(children[i]);
    }
  }
  var current = null;
  traverse(tree);

  return tree;
}

function getNode(tree, id) {
  if(typeof id === "string") id = id.split(".");
  if(id.length === 0) return tree;
  else return getNode(tree.children[id[0]], id.slice(1));
}

var tree = createSortedTree(["0", "0.1", "1", "2", "2.0", "2.1"])
var node = getNode(tree, "2.0");
console.log(node.prev.name);
console.log(node.next.name);

var node = getNode(tree, "1");
console.log(node.prev.name);
console.log(node.prevPlane.name);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jxyqjq3c/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility.  The implementation for nextNode would follow the same approach and re-use most of the function with the exception of changing the way the iterator is behaving.

```
function prevNode(collection, item, planeLock) {
  var iterator = collection.indexOf(item) - 1

  if (planeLock) {    
    while(   ~iterator 
          && !( item.split('.').length === 1 && collection[iterator].split('.').length === 1) 
          && !( item.split('.').length === collection[iterator].split('.').length && item.split('.')[0] === collection[iterator].split('.')[0] ) )
      iterator--
    return ~iterator ? collection[iterator] : false
  } else return collection[iterator] || false
}
```